# Dates display behind by a day

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm encountering some weird behavior while using Moment.js. I have some helper classes attached to the Date prototype, which are apparently are causing each date to display behind by a day.

```
Date.prototype.format = function(){
    return moment(this).format('MM/DD/YYYY')
}

var date = new Date('2008-05-13T00:00:00')

date.format() // => 05/12/2008, but should be 05/13/2008
```

A couple of other weird things I've noticed:

```
date.getDate() // => yields 12, but should be 13
```

But, if I instantiated the Moment object directly with the UTC string, then it works:

```
moment('2008-05-13T00:00:00').format('MM/DD/YY') // => 05/13/08
```

But I'm dealing with plain date objects, and modifying every date to a Moment object isn't my favorite idea. I have already tried modifying the `format` function to extract the UTC string from the date and see if it displays correctly then, but to no avail.

```
date.toUTCString() // => Correctly yields "Tue, 13 May 2008 00:00:00 GMT"

moment(date.toUTCString()).format('MM/DD/YY') // => still 05/12/08
```

Any ideas what's happening here? Is there a problem with the date constructor?

EDIT: Outputting the time as well:

```
moment(date).format('MM/DD/YY hh:mm:ss') // => "05/12/08 08:00:00"
```

Comment: output the h:m:s as well, you'll probably find that they're out by some exact number of hours, which means it's a timezone issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell moment.js that you to display the date in UTC:

```
moment(this).utc().format('MM/DD/YYYY')
```

More in the documentation: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/

---

> But, if I instantiated the Moment object directly with the UTC string, then it works:
>
> ```
> moment('2008-05-13T00:00:00').format('MM/DD/YY') // => 05/13/08`
> ```

Moment.js [interprets the argument as *local time*](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/):

> By default, moment parses and displays in local time.

Whereas `new Date()` (and `Date.parse`) [interpret the value as UTC time](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.2):

> The `parse` function [...] interprets the resulting String as a date and time; it returns a Number, the UTC time value corresponding to the date and time.

---

> I have already tried modifying the format function to extract the UTC string from the date and see if it displays correctly then, but to no avail.
>
> ```
> date.toUTCString() // => Correctly yields "Tue, 13 May 2008 00:00:00 GMT"
> moment(date.toUTCString()).format('MM/DD/YY') // => still 05/12/08`
> ```

The format that `date.toUTCString()` yields is not in any of the [formats that moment.js supports](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/), so it falls back to using `new Date()` (which interprets the string as UTC time, not local time).

Comment: This worked, hurray! Thank you. But how come the date is what I expected when I instantiated a Moment object directly with a UTC string?

Comment: Extremely helpful.  Thank you very much! Saved me some serious blank stares at the computer.